# Managing ObjectContext life time between threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, entity-framework, dispose

In a multi threaded process (**windows service**), the main thread passes an EF query (`IQueryable<>`) and a page number (`int`) to the sub-threads.

Each sub-thread takes his data using the query and the page and then process it.

I think I should create a new ObjectContext for each thread when needed.

Any other suggestions ?

<strike>Is there a way to create a query and set an ObjectContext to it later ?</strike>
- [Moved to a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777902/392335)

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use new context per thread and handle it yourselves. Context is not thread safe so sharing it among concurrent threads is way to disaster. Handling it yourselves is must if you use thread pool, if you don't have control over thread lifetime or if you want to reuse threads for multiple subsequent processings.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your app is a web application or a win application.

But the best solution is to inject it through a DI framework that can handle this for you.

For example `Ninject` has predefined Life Cycle Definitions like `InRequestScope`, `InThreadScope`, `InSingletonScope` and ....

It also prevents connection and memory leaks.

Comment: So defining it as a singleton property would be the best solution IMHO.