# Changing the ObjectContext of an existing IQueryable<>

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a method that gets a query that I want to execute with some addons (count, paging) on different threads.

The method can get different queries that returns the same `IQueryable<someEntity>`.

Is there a way to create an EF query and set the ObjectContext to it later ?

thanks.

Comment: Is using [`ObjectQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303.aspx) an option for you?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure how to create a linq expression that will return an ObjectQuery. Please elaborate.

Comment: With `ObjectQuery` you use query strings like this: `"SELECT VALUE product FROM AdventureWorksEntities.Products AS product"`. They remain modifiable until they are executed: you can append a `where` clause, skip/take to get a particular slice of the data, et cetera.

Comment: But all the ctors of ObjectQuery requires an ObjectContext...

Comment: Yes, that's the part that may make it useful to you. Each thread would have its own `ObjectContext`. You would pass each thread a string, the thread would make it into an `ObjectQuery`, add paging, and run as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. IQueryable (and ObjectQuery) is dependent on context which created it. As a workaround you can use custom static method containing your query, returning IQueryable and accepting context as parameter. The same priciple is followed by pre-compiled queries which are context independent.

Comment: But my method can get different queries which return the same IQueryable<Entity> to process. when I execute my query, I don't know what it's querying.

Comment: Either your comment doesn't make sense or you didn't describe the problem in question correctly. The method will contain only the base query and because it will return IQueryable you will be able to add other conditions or paging when you use it.

Comment: I have just saw you other question so the context is more understandable know. You can still use the approach I mentioned and pass delegate to those different static methods with different queries from the main thread to worker threads. Those threads will call received delegate and pass their context as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As Ladislav Mrnka's says, you can store a delegate to achieve this. I was doing this before Googling for a way to "transplant" an IQueryable from one DbContext to another. I was glad to see my approach validated :)

Here's a concrete example:

```
// keep your delegate somewhere
private Func<MyDbContext, IQueryable<MyEntity>> _queryFactory;

// create the query
_queryFactory = db => db.MyEntities.Where(x => x.Something == "ABC");

// when you want to "attach" the query:
var query = _queryFactory(new MyDbContext());
var result = query.ToList();

// you can also conditionally build on the query
if(something)
{
    var closure = _queryFactory; // StackOverflow without this
    _queryFactory = db =>
        closure(db).Where(x => x.SomethingElse > 123);
}
```

And as usual, be careful when creating closures.